# Acceder a un campo especifico de una lista

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. Deseo obtener el registro mas reciente de una lista, para con dicho registro ingresar a la misma lista y tener acceso al resto de campos de la misma para tomar los datos de mi interés.
Para ello, lo primero que hago es obtener el registro mas reciente de la lista así:

```
var q = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                where
                    a.id == IdLlanta
                group a by a.id into GrupoA
                select new CountCargo
                {
                    Cargo = GrupoA.Key,
                    Count = GrupoA.Max(a => a.Registro)
                };
        var q1 = q.ToList();
```

`q1` me entrega los siguientes resultados:

```
[
  {
    "cargo": "106534",
    "count": 16244
  }
]
```

Luego, necesito acceder al campo "count" de `q1`, el cual me da un dato único en la base de datos, con dicho dato, podre hacer un consulta que tenga un `WHERE` que solicite el valor que tiene "count".

Como pueden notar `q1`, tiene dos campos "cargo" y "count", pero yo solo necesito tener el dato que se encuentra en "count". Pensé que para obtener ese dato, lo podría hacer de una de las siguientes formas:

```
q1.count;
o
q1.[count];
o
q1.(count);
```

Ninguna de estas formas me funcionó. Agradezco por favor me indiquen cómo puedo hacer para acceder al campo "count" de la lista `q1` y poderlo usar en una consulta posterior que debo hacer.

Comment: Esto te puede ser de ayuda: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que tú **variable q1** es una lista, y la propiedad a la que quieres acceder pertenece a cada **objeto anónimo** que se guarda como elemento de la lista obtenida, es decir tú tienes una lista de n-elementos, donde cada elemento es un **objeto anónimo** con las **propiedades Cargo** y **Count**. Para acceder a los elementos de esa lista puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Si estás seguro que tú consulta original devuelve un elemento podrías usar el **método FirstOrDefault**, el cual devuelve el primer elemento de la lista en caso de que la lista no esté vacía, y de estar vacía devuelve **null**:

```
var objeto = q1.FirstOrDefault();
int total = 0;

if(objeto != null)
{
    total = objeto.Count;
}
```

Si deseas recorrer todos los elementos de la lista puedes usar un **ciclo foreach**:

```
int total = 0;

foreach(var o in q1)
{
    total = o.Count;
    //Hacer algo mas
}
```

Aquí recorro cada elemento de la lista y por cada elemento de la lista accedo a su **propiedad Count**.

**Nota**: Mi respuesta es general para que cojas más vista a la hora de usar **Linq**, analiza está respuesta y adáptala a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

En C#, cuando usas LINQ para realizar consultas, el resultado se proyecta en un tipo específico (en tu caso, el tipo CountCargo). Para acceder al valor de count en el resultado de tu consulta LINQ, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
List<CountCargo> q1 = 
 resultado)
CountCargo primerResultado = q1.FirstOrDefault();

if (primerResultado != null)
{
    int valorCount = primerResultado.Count;

   
}
```

La función FirstOrDefault() se utiliza para obtener el primer elemento de la lista o el valor predeterminado del tipo si la lista está vacía. Luego, puedes acceder al campo Count del objeto CountCargo para obtener el valor que necesitas.